# how matching URI using Route annotation on symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-3.2

**example case  URI:** '/department/id/1'

**Controller:**

```
/**

     @Route/department/id/{slug}
*/
        function($slug)
        return new Response($slug)
```

it return me '1'

**if I have URI:**/department/id/1/category/id/2

how to form the @Route    that capture 1 and 2  ?

please help thanks

Comment: i think you really should read the symfony documentation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 @Route(/department/{slug}/category/{id}, name='department_category_detail')
*/
public function departmentCagetegoryDetailAction($slug, $id) {
    ....
}
```